# Aggregating data hourly using diffrent metric ( skew) in Panadas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, signal-processing

I have a  large datatable that are obtained from sensor data and look like this:

```
    Code                             A1    A2  A3 ... AB40
    Time
2000-01-01 00:00:10.730              NaN   1   NaN    NaN
2010-01-01 00:00:12.730              1     2   3      NaN
```

There are some period of time and there is no data available which is related to the time the device is off. I want to aggregate data every one hour. 
I used the following code:

```
telemetry_mean=pd.pivot_table(Telemetry,  index='Time').resample('1H').mean().dropna(how='all')
telemetry_mean=pd.pivot_table(Telemetry,  index='Time').resample('1H').std().dropna(how='all')
    # renaming the columns 
telemetry_mean.columns = [i + 'mean_5T' for i in list(telemetry_mean)]
telemetry_std.columns = [i + 'Std_5T' for i in list(telemetry_std)]
telemetry_feat = pd.concat([ telemetry_mean,   telemetry_std]
```

I cant apply the same method to get the skew metric or kurtosis metric of the signal based on given window of time,  and I get different structure:

```
telemetry_Skew=pd.pivot_table(Telemetry,  index='Time').resample('1H').skew().dropna(how='all')
```

output

```
Code
A1                                 0.762252
A2                                 0.021107
A3                                 -1.035745
A4                                  0.578501
```

What am I missing here?

I am also wondering if there is more elegant way to calculate all these statistical metric in one referral to the data ( due to large nature of data). so  for e.g. instead using `telemetry_Skew=pd.pivot_table(Telemetry,  index='Time').resample('1H').skew().dropna(how='all') for each statistic I can do mean, std and ... in one referral to the data.

I appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The output that I am looking for is in this format

```
                                     A1                A2      ........ AB40      
    Time                           mean std skew  mean std skew
2000-01-01 00:00:00.00             1    2    0    2    1    9
.
.
.
2010-01-01 00:01:00.00              1   2    3    1    0    1
```

I randomly filled the mean, std, skew for description

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.
It sounds much simpler, but I'm not sure it will fit your needs.

```
# setting the time as index
df = df.set_index('Time')
# grouping by hour
grouped = df.groupby(df.index.hour)
# computing various stats
grouped = grouped.agg(['std', 'mean', 'skew']).transpose().unstack()
# cosmetics dropping a useless column level
grouped.columns = grouped.columns.droplevel()

grouped

#            std  mean  skew
# A1         NaN   1.0   NaN
# A2    0.707107   1.5   NaN
# A3         NaN   3.0   NaN
# AB40       NaN   NaN   NaN
```

### Alternative

Starting from pandas 0.20 you can use `agg` directly on the `DataFrame` to compute various stats. See detail [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html).
It should be worth considering it for what you are trying to do.

```
df.agg(['std', 'mean', 'skew']).transpose()

#            std  mean  skew
# A1         NaN   1.0   NaN
# A2    0.707107   1.5   NaN
# A3         NaN   3.0   NaN
# AB40       NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Romain for your comments. When I am trying to use `df = df.set_index('Time')` I get the KeyError: 'Time'. The Time show up when I print my data table but I cant call it as column.  I think this is related to multiindex but not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Hello, I think you're right it's because of the shape of the `DataFrame` either of the rows or of the columns. But it's hard to figure out with only the string representation its exact shape. Maybe you do not need to set the index if it's already set. I've proposed an alternative in my answer that you could consider.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this. You comment was very helpful,  I tried to modify what you provided and with using 
 `grouped = df.groupby(df.index.hour)
  grouped = grouped.agg(['std', 'mean', 'skew'])`
 I got to something that is closest to what I want. The only issue is that I lose the format of my Time column and it becomes numeric index ` 0 1 2 3 4` is there any way to preserve the original format of time and date that  I have?
 I updated my question to explain better the format that I am looking for